# Bundled Realm DB, but empty ResultSet

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to load a bundled realm DB in my project, but my ResultSet is just empty. I've generated to bundled DB in Realm Studio:

[image]

Copied it to the project and added it to the target. I've created a Realm object as follows:

```
class StopRealm: Object {

    @objc dynamic var stop_id = 0
    @objc dynamic var stop_code = ""
    @objc dynamic var stop_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var stop_desc = ""
    @objc dynamic var stop_lat = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var stop_lon = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var location_type = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var parent_station = ""

}
```

And I'm trying to load the DB like this:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration( fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "StopsRealm", withExtension: "realm"), readOnly: true)
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
        let results = realm.objects(StopRealm.self)
        print(results)
```

However this leaves me with an empty ResultSet. Any ideas how to fix it?

Update:

Changing the class name to "StopsRealm" worked, and using the "Save model definitions" in Realm Studio, my model should look like this:

```
let stop_id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    @objc dynamic var stop_code: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var stop_name: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var stop_desc: String? = nil
    let stop_lat = RealmOptional<Double>()
    let stop_lon = RealmOptional<Double>()
    let location_type = RealmOptional<Int>()
    @objc dynamic var parent_station: String? = nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a mismatch in class naming: "StopsRealm" vs. "StopRealm".

Comment: You're right! I get the error: "Domain=io.realm Code=1 "The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_id' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_code' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_name' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_desc' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_lat' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.stop_lon' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.location_type' has been made required.
- Property 'StopsRealm.parent_station' has been made required."

Comment: So now that your code model is named as the model in the database, there is a conflict between property types. You should explicitly declare your class properties as optional when they are in fact optional in the database.

Comment: Another question, I see that you're adviced to make the db compact before releasing the app, is a bundled db from Realm Studio already compact?

Comment: Did I advise such thing? :) What is the size of your db?

Comment: Not "you" as you, but in general ;o) My realmDB is about 12 mb

Comment: Oh, excuse my English :) The size seems okay, make sure to implement 'shouldCompactOnLaunch' in your app and you are good.